# ASP.NET Development Server 403 Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I'm developing a web application in Visual Studio 2010 on Win 7, and now seem to have a new error that has just popped up.  When I try to access the site which uses Windows Authentication, in Firefox, I get a 403 error, with no subcodes.  Up until this poijnt, it has been working this way just fine.  Firefox prompts me for my credentials, and I enter them and then I get the 403 error.  No problems with it in IE, just Firefox.

I've checked the network-trusted-ntlm-automatic key in Firefox and deleted my session cookie, but still no luck.  The problem seems to be limited only to Firefox.

If I set the app to be Anon access, it works with no problems, but the app needs to be Windows Auth.

I attempted Local IIS, but there wasn't an option for Windows Auth for the app on my local IIS, so that kind of removed that option for the time being.

Any ideas out there for how to get this working correctly again?  I'll take answers that get me the Windows Auth option in my local IIS as well, because that would also fix the problem for me.

Comment: What happens if you browse to it using Firefox "private" mode?

Comment: To read the real error on ii7 you need to call it from the computer it self, or to read the Events on event viewer.

Comment: @Justin M. Keyes No difference between Private mode and regular in Firefox with this problem

Comment: @Aristos Reading the Event log, I see an error that indicates Account Lockout, but only when I try to hit the site with Firefox.  All other things using my network credentials appear to be OK, and AD servers do not indicate an account lockout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I finally found the answer, but it wasn't where I expected it.

I was digging through Event Viewer trying to figure out why I kept getting Account Lockout messages when trying to load the site with Firefox and did some searching came across an article that specified how to add multiple servers to the Firefox **network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris** key in about:config.

I had specified:

**http://host1; http://host2**

and instead should have separated with commas

**http://host1, http://host2**

I changed it to commas and reloaded and it is now working correctly with the Windows Authentication in Firefox.

Hopefully someone else finds this particular fix useful.  Small typo, big headache.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure directory browsing is not enabled for the site. Also, make sure your default documents are setup so when you go to: http://www.yoursite.com/ (notice the slash at the end of the url) a default document is loaded. I have seen in some cases where IIS thinks you want to browse the directory rather than load a page. See if you still get the 403 error by going to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running windows 7, 64bit with IIS 6.1.

To turn on Windows Authentication, go to Control Panel -> Administrative tools and select IIS Manager.

In the left panel, expand Sites, Default Web Site, and select your Virtual Directory.  You should see Asp.Net in the top panel and IIS in the middle.  The first icon under the IIS section is Authentication, double click this.  You can then disable annon and enable windows by selecting from the drop down list and clicking Enable / Disable from the actions on the right side of the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI - you are not running IIS 6.1.  There was never a 6.1 release.  If you're running Windows 7 then the IIS version you have installed is 7.5